# Looping through result set, I need to update a table when a condition is met

Tags: java, database, loops, jdbc, resultset

I have a loop in my code. It iterates over the result set. Whenever the value of `qc = 0`, it should update a table in the database.

But it is only updating the database table only for the first time it comes across `qc = 0`. And then it just comes out of the while loop. It does not go for the next iteration to check for another value of "qc"

```
String sql5 =  "select  t$pdno ,t$opno, t$qcmp , t$qtbf from ttisfc010100 where t$pdno = "+pdno+" and t$opno <= "+opno ;
ResultSet getData3 = db.getStmt().executeQuery(sql5);
while(getData3.next()) {
    int pd , op , qc , qt ;
    pd = getData3.getInt(1);
    op = getData3.getInt(2);
    qc = getData3.getInt(3);
    qt = getData3.getInt(4);
    String sql7="";
    if(qc==0)
    {
       sql7 = "update ttisfc010100 set t$qcmp = "+quantity+" , t$qtbf = "+quantity+"   where t$pdno = "+pd+" and t$opno = "+op;
       db.getStmt().executeUpdate(sql7); 
    }    
}
catch (SQLException e) {

e.printStackTrace();  }
```

The `getStmt()` method contains the logic to create a normal statement . See below :

```
public class DatabaseConnection 
{

Statement stmt;

public void openConnection() {
    Class.forName(classForName);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(driver+dsn, user, password); 
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
}

public Statement getStmt()
{
    if(stmt==null)
    {

       stmt = this.getNewStmt();

    }

    return stmt;
}

public Statement getNewStmt() {
    Statement newStmt;
    try {
        newStmt = conn.createStatement();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        newStmt = stmt;
    }

    return newStmt;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend changing how you execute the SQL to use `PreparedStatements`. This is to prevent SQL Injection

Comment: You have SQL-injection vulnerability. You can remove it by using `PreparedStatements` with placeholders `?` which you will later set to data you want to use in query, for instance with `stmt.setInt(1, pdno);`

Comment: "*And then it just comes out of the while loop. It does not go for the next iteration*" is it possible that while update your code throws exception which breaks your loop? Can we see how you handle `SQLException`?

Comment: Don't post important informations only as comments (especially if it is code example which can't be properly formatted in comment). Instead use [edit] option to add it to your question.

Comment: are there any errorcodes you could show us from Eclipse or whatever?

Comment: What is this method for in your code? --> getStmt()

 you should also show us your declaration of db.

Comment: the getStmt() has logic to create a new statement . I have edited my post . Please refer it . Added the getStmt()  method .

Comment: Hi , I used prepared statement and it worked perfectly . Can you please tell why it didn't work with normal statement ?  And what do you mean by sql injection  ?

Answer (score 1):

I have removed the usage of Normal statement , and used a prepared statement in my code . Now that solved my problem .

Thanks a lot . You people are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you reuse the same `Statement` to execute your second query in the loop. When you execute a new query on the same `Statement` object, any previously opened statements on that same object are closed, including their result sets.

I am a bit surprised that you don't receive a `SQLException` that the result set is closed.

Also note that a class like your `DatabaseConnection` is a bit weird, as it makes correctly managing JDBC resources harder, not easier.